# Finding conditional and joint probabilities from a simulation

Tags: r, markov-chains, markov

Consider the Markov chain with state space *S = {1, 2}* and transition matrix

[image]

and initial distribution *α = (1/2, 1/2)*.

Suppose, the source code for simulation is the following:

```
alpha <- c(1, 1) / 2
mat <- matrix(c(1 / 2, 0, 1 / 2, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2) 

chainSim <- function(alpha, mat, n) 
{
  out <- numeric(n)
  out[1] <- sample(1:2, 1, prob = alpha)
  for(i in 2:n)
    out[i] <- sample(1:2, 1, prob = mat[out[i - 1], ])
  out
}
```

Suppose the following is the result of a 5-step Markov Chain simulation repeated 10 times:

```
> sim
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2    1    1    2    2    2    1    1    1     2
[2,]    2    1    2    2    2    2    2    1    1     2
[3,]    2    1    2    2    2    2    2    1    2     2
[4,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    1    2     2
[5,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[6,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
```

What would be the values of the following?

1. *P(X<sub>1</sub> = 1, X<sub>3</sub> = 1)*
2. *P(X<sub>5</sub> = 2 | X<sub>0</sub> = 1, X<sub>2</sub> = 1)*
3. *E(X<sub>2</sub>)*

I tried them as follows:

1. `mean(sim[4, ] == 1 && sim[2, ]== 1)`
2. ?
3. `c(1,2) * mean(sim[2, ])`

What would be (2)? Am I correct with the rest?

Kindly explain your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct about 1: there is a difference whether you use `&&` or `&`, see

```
?`&&`
```

It should be

```
mean(sim[1 + 1, ] == 1 & sim[1 + 3, ] == 1)
```

Then 2 is given by

```
mean(sim[1 + 5, sim[1 + 0, ] == 1 & sim[1 + 2, ] == 1] == 2)
```

where you may get `NaN` in the case if the conditional event {X<sub>0</sub> = 1, X<sub>2</sub> = 1} doesn't appear in your simulation.

Lastly, point 3 is

```
mean(sim[1 + 2, ])
```

since a natural estimator of the expected value is simply the sample average.

Comment: @user366312, `mean(sim[2, ])` gives just a number, while `c(1,2)` is a vector. Even if `mean(sim[2, ])` were a vector, you would need to sum the result. Also, not always there are going to be both ones and twos among your results. A correct version of your solution would be `sum(as.numeric(names(table(sim[2, ]))) * table(sim[2, ]) / 10)`. Lastly, you need row 3 rather than 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take advantage of the problem structure, state 2 is an absorbing state. The only way for *X<sub>1</sub>=1* and *X<sub>3</sub>=1* is if it begins with 1 and in every intermediate step, it keep visiting state 1. Hence, the answer is *(0.5)<sup>4</sup>=0.0625*.

In terms of simulation, rather than

```
mean(sim[4, ] == 1 && sim[2, ]== 1
```

It should be

```
mean(sim[4, ] == 1 & sim[2, ]== 1
```

&& only check the first component.

2. For the second part, one possible way is to note that

*P(X<sub>5</sub>=2|X<sub>0</sub>=1, X<sub>2</sub>=1)=P(X<sub>5</sub>=2,X<sub>0</sub>=1, X<sub>2</sub>=1)/P(X<sub>0</sub>=1, X<sub>2</sub>=1)*

of which you can then first estimate the numerator and the denominator separately and then compute the ratio.

Alternatively, *P(X<sub>5</sub>=2|X<sub>0</sub>=1, X<sub>2</sub>=1)=P(X<sub>5</sub>=2| X<sub>2</sub>=1)=P(X<sub>3</sub>=2| X<sub>0</sub>=1)*

3. For the third question, *E(X<sub>2</sub>)* is a single number, it is not a vector. It can be estimated by `mean(sim[3,])`